# STS Configuration: Local Login Provider is missing it's signing certificate

Tags: sharepoint-addin, active-directory, claims-based-auth, azure

One of our Sharepoint farms is stuck on "User Profile Synchronization Service" Starting

Any idea how to give a signing certificate to "Local Login Provider"?

other errors in ULS:

```
04/04/2014 17:15:58.22  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0860)   0x08EC  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Timer Job Power Pivot Health Statistics Collector Timer Job    a3fe839c-01d9-a0ee-1fee-9cbbe1f5e5bf
04/04/2014 17:15:58.22  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0860)   0x08EC  SharePoint Foundation   Topology    aeayb   Medium  SecurityTokenServiceSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc/actas' Channel: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.IWSTrustChannelContract' Action: 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/RST/Issue' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:4057d464-399b-4ac6-8372-9b2db7e215d9'   a3fe839c-01d9-a0ee-1fee-9cbbe1f5e5bf
04/04/2014 17:15:58.24  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0860)   0x08EC  SharePoint Foundation   Claims Authentication   fsq7    High    SPSecurityContext: Request for security token failed with exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The requested service, 'http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc/actas' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.IWSTrustContract.Issue(Message message)     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst, RequestSecurityTokenResponse& rstr)     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForContext(Uri context, Boolean bearerToken, SecurityToken onBehalfOf, SecurityToken actAs, SecurityToken delegateTo, SPRequestSecurityTokenProperties properties)   a3fe839c-01d9-a0ee-1fee-9cbbe1f5e5bf
04/04/2014 17:15:58.24  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0860)   0x08EC  SharePoint Foundation   Claims Authentication   8306    Critical    An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The requested service, 'http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc/actas' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information..    a3fe839c-01d9-a0ee-1fee-9cbbe1f5e5bf
04/04/2014 17:15:58.24  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0860)   0x08EC  PowerPivot Service  Usage   99  High    EXCEPTION: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The requested service, 'http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc/actas' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.IWSTrustContract.Issue(Message message)     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst, RequestSecurityTokenResponse& rstr)     at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForContext(Uri context, Boolean bearerToken, SecurityToken onBehalfOf, SecurityToken actAs, SecurityToken delegateTo, SPRequestSecurityTokenProperties properties)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.<>c__DisplayClassc.<GetProcessSecurityTokenForServiceContext>b__b()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.GetProcessSecurityTokenForServiceContext()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForServiceContext(Uri contextUri)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChannelFactoryOperations.InternalCreateChannelActingAsLoggedOnUser[TChannel](ChannelFactory`1 factory, EndpointAddress address, Uri via)     at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.GeminiServiceApplicationProxy.GetGeminiServiceApplicationChannel(Uri endpointAddress)     at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin.UsageHealthCollectionTimerJob.Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)  a3fe839c-01d9-a0ee-1fee-9cbbe1f5e5bf
04/04/2014 17:15:58.25  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0860)   0x08EC  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job Power Pivot Health Statistics Collector Timer Job). Execution Time=29.1213   a3fe839c-01d9-a0ee-1fee-9cbbe1f5e5bf




04/04/2014 17:25:12.45  w3wp.exe (0x2C4C)   0x1B74  SharePoint Foundation   Runtime tkau    Unexpected  Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileApplicationNotAvailableException: This User Profile Application's connection is currently not available. The Application Pool or User Profile Service may not have been started. Please contact your administrator.    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.UserProfiles.AdminUI.ProfileAdminPage.get_CurrentApplicationProxy()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.UserProfiles.AdminUI.ManageUserProfileServiceApplicationBase.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  2aff839c-e1ce-a0ee-1fee-973fc0130e37
```

Answer (score 0):

look alike know issue with one of the security update. You need to either uninstall the following hotfix(Security Update for Microsoft Windows (KB2756920) from server.

other is apply this hotfix.http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2637518
Source: [Secure Token Service (STS) Missing Method – KB2752920](http://thesharepointproject.com/tag/secure-token-service/)

if above failed try this one:
[Unable to Activate Security Token Service Application - Event ID 8306](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2520344?ppud=4&wa=wsignin1.0)